# J2ME: Uncaught exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (stack trace incomplete)

Tags: java, memory, java-me, midp

I am creating a J2ME game that has 10 levels, 2 coins, a staircase, background music, a monster and a set of spikes. When I get to the second level of the game I get this error - I know this is because I am running out of memory.

Is there any way I can improve my code below to prevent this error from happening, or is there anyway I can fix this?

```
public class QuatschCanvas
    extends GameCanvas
    implements Runnable {

/**
 * @return the points
*
 * WHAT HAS TO BE DONE TO THE GAME
 * fix the door bug for all the levels after level 1
 * add 2 more coins
 * make the coins appear and disappear at different times but in the same place
 * add music to game
 * add sound when you hit a wall or die
 * add methods to fix up the code and make it look nice
 * fix record store to highest score
 * get game going back to main menu when finished
 * add animation to the main menu
 */
public boolean mTrucking;
private LayerManager mLayerManager;
private TiledLayer mAtmosphere, mBackground, mCollisionBackground, mCollisionDoor;
private int mAnimatedIndex;
private Sprite mQuatsch, mCoin,mCoin2, mMonster, mKey, mStairs, mSpikesUp, mSpikesDown;
private Graphics graphics;
Image gameOver, youWin;
private static int mState, mDirection, dState;
private static final int kStanding = 1;
private static final int kRunning = 2;
private static final int kRunningUp = 3;
private static final int kRunningDown = 4;
private static final int kCoinSpin = 5;
private static final int kMonsterMoveUp = 6;
private static final int kMonsterMoveDown = 7;
private static final int kLeft = 1;
private static final int kRight = 2;
private static final int kUp = 3;
private static final int kDown = 4;
private static int lives = 3;
private static int coins = 0;
private static int points = 0;
public static int currentLevel = 1;
public static int countForLevels = 0;
private static int keys = 0;
private static final int[] kRunningSequence = {0, 1, 0, 2};
private static final int[] kStandingSequence = {0};
private static final int[] kRunningSequenceUp = {3, 4, 3, 5};
private static final int[] kRunningSequenceDown = {6, 7, 6, 8};
private static final int[] kCoinSpinning = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
private static final int[] kMonsterDown = {0, 1, 2, 1};
private static final int[] kMonsterUp = {9, 10, 11, 10};
private static int infinateLoop, spikeLoop;

public QuatschCanvas(String quatschImageName,
        String atmosphereImageName, String backgroundImageName, String coinName, String monsterName,
        String keyName, String stairsName, String spikesNameUp, String spikesNameDown) throws IOException {
    super(true);

    // Create a LayerManager.
    mLayerManager = new LayerManager();
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    mLayerManager.setViewWindow(96, 0, w, h);

    createBackground(backgroundImageName, 0);
    createAtmosphere(atmosphereImageName);
    createQuatsch(quatschImageName);
    createCoin(coinName);
    createSecondCoin(coinName);
    createMonster(monsterName);
    createKey(keyName);
    createStairs(stairsName);
    createSpikesUp(spikesNameUp);
    createSpikesDown(spikesNameDown);

    gameOver = Image.createImage("/game-over.png");
    youWin = Image.createImage("/you-win.png");
}

private void createBackground(String backgroundImageName, int level)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the tiled layer.
    Image backgroundImage = Image.createImage(backgroundImageName);

    mCollisionDoor = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96);
    mCollisionDoor.setPosition(12, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < doorMap[level].length; i++) {
        int column = i % 8;
        int row = (i - column) / 8;
        mCollisionDoor.setCell(column, row, doorMap[level][i]);
    }
    mAnimatedIndex = mCollisionDoor.createAnimatedTile(8);
    //mCollisionBackground.setCell(3, 1, mAnimatedIndex);
    mLayerManager.append(mCollisionDoor);

    mBackground = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96);
    mBackground.setPosition(12, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < map[level].length; i++) {
        int column = i % 8;
        int row = (i - column) / 8;
        mBackground.setCell(column, row, map[level][i]);
    }
    mAnimatedIndex = mBackground.createAnimatedTile(8);
    // mBackground.setCell(3, 1, mAnimatedIndex);
    mLayerManager.append(mBackground);

    mCollisionBackground = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96);
    mCollisionBackground.setPosition(12, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < collsionMap[level].length; i++) {
        int column = i % 8;
        int row = (i - column) / 8;
        mCollisionBackground.setCell(column, row, collsionMap[level][i]);
    }
    mAnimatedIndex = mCollisionBackground.createAnimatedTile(8);
    //mCollisionBackground.setCell(3, 1, mAnimatedIndex);
    mLayerManager.append(mCollisionBackground);


}

private void createAtmosphere(String atmosphereImageName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the atmosphere layer
    Image atmosphereImage = Image.createImage(atmosphereImageName);
    mAtmosphere = new TiledLayer(8, 1, atmosphereImage,
            atmosphereImage.getWidth(), atmosphereImage.getHeight());
    mAtmosphere.fillCells(0, 0, 8, 1, 1);
    mAtmosphere.setPosition(0, 192);

    mLayerManager.insert(mAtmosphere, 0);
}

private void createQuatsch(String quatschImageName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the sprite.
    Image quatschImage = Image.createImage(quatschImageName);
    mQuatsch = new Sprite(quatschImage, 48, 48);
    mQuatsch.setPosition(96 + (getWidth() - 48) / 2, 100);
    mQuatsch.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setDirection(kLeft);
    setState(kStanding);
    mLayerManager.insert(mQuatsch, 1);
}

private void createKey(String keyName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the sprite.
    Image keyImage = Image.createImage(keyName);
    mKey = new Sprite(keyImage, 48, 48);
    mKey.setPosition(250, 110);
    mKey.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setState(kStanding);
    mLayerManager.insert(mKey, 0);
}

private void createSpikesUp(String spikesNameUp)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the sprite.
    Image spikesImageUp = Image.createImage(spikesNameUp);
    mSpikesUp = new Sprite(spikesImageUp, 48, 48);
    //mSpikes.setPosition(200, 110);
    mSpikesUp.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setState(kStanding);
    mLayerManager.insert(mSpikesUp, 0);
}

private void createSpikesDown(String spikesNameDown)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the sprite.
    Image spikesImageDown = Image.createImage(spikesNameDown);
    mSpikesDown = new Sprite(spikesImageDown, 48, 48);
    //mSpikes.setPosition(200, 110);
    mSpikesDown.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setState(kStanding);
    mLayerManager.insert(mSpikesDown, 0);
}

private void createStairs(String stairsName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the sprite.
    Image stairsImage = Image.createImage(stairsName);
    mStairs = new Sprite(stairsImage, 48, 48);
    mStairs.setPosition(130, 520);
    mStairs.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setState(kStanding);
    mLayerManager.insert(mStairs, 0);
}

private void createCoin(String coinName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the atmosphere layer
    Image coinImage = Image.createImage(coinName);
    mCoin = new Sprite(coinImage, 48, 48);
    mCoin.setPosition(500, 150);
    mCoin.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setState(kCoinSpin);
    mLayerManager.insert(mCoin, 0);
}

private void createSecondCoin(String coinName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the atmosphere layer
    Image coinImage = Image.createImage(coinName);
    mCoin2 = new Sprite(coinImage, 48, 48);
    mCoin2.setPosition(250, 220);
    mCoin2.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setState(kCoinSpin);
    mLayerManager.insert(mCoin2, 0);
}

private void createMonster(String monsterName)
        throws IOException {
    // Create the atmosphere layer
    Image monsterImage = Image.createImage(monsterName);
    mMonster = new Sprite(monsterImage, 48, 48);
    mMonster.setPosition(520, 500);
    mMonster.defineReferencePixel(24, 24);
    setDirection(kUp);
    setState(kMonsterMoveUp);
    mLayerManager.insert(mMonster, 0);
}

public void start() {
    mTrucking = true;
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void run() {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    int frameCount = 0;
    int factor = 2;
    int animatedDelta = 0;

InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio/mainsong.mp3");
Player p; 
    try {
        p = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");
        p.setLoopCount(-1);
        p.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MediaException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }






    while (mTrucking) {
        // create timer for the dragon to move up the map
        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask firstTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                setDragonState(kMonsterMoveUp);
                mMonster.move(0, -3);
                mSpikesUp.setVisible(true);
                mSpikesDown.setVisible(false);
                mCoin.setVisible(false);
                mCoin.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // create a timer for the dragon to move down the map
        TimerTask secondTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                setDragonState(kMonsterMoveDown);
                mMonster.move(0, 3);
                mSpikesUp.setVisible(false);
                mSpikesDown.setVisible(true);
                mCoin.setVisible(true);
                mCoin.setVisible(false);
            }
        };

        // continueos loop so the dragon will keep moving up and down the map
        if (infinateLoop >= 0 && infinateLoop < 50) {
            aTimer.schedule(firstTask, 1000);
            infinateLoop = infinateLoop + 1;
            mMonster.nextFrame();
        } else if (infinateLoop >= 50 && infinateLoop < 100) {
            aTimer.schedule(secondTask, 1000);
            infinateLoop = infinateLoop + 1;
            mMonster.nextFrame();
        } else {
            infinateLoop = 0;
        }


        // what to do if the player hits a coin

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCoin, true)) {        
            mCoin.setVisible(false);
            coins++;
            setPoints(getPoints() + 20);
        }

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCoin2, true)) {
            mCoin2.setVisible(false);
            coins++;
            setPoints(getPoints() + 20);
        }

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mStairs, true)) {
            aTimer.cancel();
            firstTask.cancel();
            secondTask.cancel();
            countForLevels++;
            if(countForLevels<10){

            for (int i = 0; i < map[countForLevels].length; i++) {
                int column = i % 8;
                int row = (i - column) / 8;
                mBackground.setCell(column, row, map[countForLevels][i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < collsionMap[countForLevels].length; i++) {
                int column = i % 8;
                int row = (i - column) / 8;
                mCollisionBackground.setCell(column, row, collsionMap[countForLevels][i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < doorMap[countForLevels].length; i++) {
                int column = i % 8;
                int row = (i - column) / 8;
                mCollisionDoor.setCell(column, row, doorMap[countForLevels][i]);
            }
            mCollisionDoor.setVisible(true);
            mKey.setVisible(true);
            mCoin.setVisible(true);
            mCoin2.setVisible(true);
            mLayerManager.append(mBackground);
            mLayerManager.append(mCollisionBackground);
            mLayerManager.append(mCollisionDoor);

            //resetItems(int bg_x, int bg_y, int s_x, int s_y, int k_x, int k_y, int su_x, int su_y, int sd_x, int sd_y, int m_x, int m_y, int c_x, int c_y)
            if (countForLevels == 1) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, 70);//170
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 515);//115
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300);
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215);
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525);
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40);
            }
            }
        }

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mSpikesUp, true)) {
            if (countForLevels == 1) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 115);
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300);
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215);
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525);
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40);
            }
            lives--;
        }

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mSpikesDown, true)) {
           if (countForLevels == 1) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 115);
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300);
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215);
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525);
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40);
            }
            lives--;
        }

        // what to do if a player hits a key
        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mKey, true)) {
            mKey.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println(keys);
            keys = keys + 1;
            setPoints(getPoints() + 50);
            System.out.println(keys);
        }

        // what to do if the player hits a monster
        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mMonster, true)) {
            if (countForLevels == 1) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 115);
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300);
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215);
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170);
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) {
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525);
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) {
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40);
            }
            lives--;
        }

        if (isShown()) {
            int keyStates = getKeyStates();
            if ((keyStates & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
                setDirection(kLeft);
                movingCharacter(kRunning, 10, 0, -10, 0);

            } else if ((keyStates & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
                setDirection(kRight);
                movingCharacter(kRunning, -10, 0, 10, 0);

            } else if ((keyStates & UP_PRESSED) != 0) {
                movingCharacter(kRunningUp, 0, 10, 0, -10);

            } else if ((keyStates & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) {
                movingCharacter(kRunningDown, 0, -10, 0, 10);

            } else {
                setState(kStanding);
                mCoin.nextFrame();
                mCoin2.nextFrame();
            }

            frameCount++;
            if (frameCount % factor == 0) {
                int delta = 1;
                if (frameCount / factor < 10) {
                    delta = -1;
                }
                mAtmosphere.move(delta, 0);
                if (frameCount / factor == 20) {
                    frameCount = 0;
                }

                mBackground.setAnimatedTile(mAnimatedIndex,
                        8 + animatedDelta++);
                if (animatedDelta == 3) {
                    animatedDelta = 0;
                }
            }

            g.setColor(0x5b1793);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

            mLayerManager.paint(g, 0, 0);

            flushGraphics();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(80);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        if (lives == 0) {
            stop();
            g.drawImage(gameOver,10,50,Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);
            repaint();
        }

        if(countForLevels == 10){
            stop();
            g.drawImage(youWin,10,50,Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);
            repaint();
        }
    }
    //String pointsString = Integer.toString(points);
    //String levelString = Integer.toString(level);

    //mScoreListener.collectItems(pointsString, levelString);

    System.out.println("Points = " + getPoints() + "\nLevel = " + currentLevel);
}

public void movingCharacter(int state, int x, int y, int a, int b) {
    setState(state);
    mBackground.move(x, y);
    mCollisionBackground.move(x, y);
    mCollisionDoor.move(x, y);
    mAtmosphere.move(x, y);
    mCoin.move(x, y);
    mCoin2.move(x, y);
    mStairs.move(x, y);
    mMonster.move(x, y);
    mKey.move(x, y);
    mQuatsch.nextFrame();
    mCoin.nextFrame();
    mCoin2.nextFrame();
    mSpikesUp.move(x, y);
    mSpikesDown.move(x, y);
    // if the player hits a wall
    if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCollisionBackground, true)) {
        mBackground.move(a, b);
        mCollisionBackground.move(a, b);
        mCollisionDoor.move(a, b);
        mAtmosphere.move(a, b);
        mCoin.move(a, b);
        mCoin2.move(a, b);
        mStairs.move(a, b);
        mKey.move(a, b);
        mMonster.move(a, b);
        mSpikesUp.move(a, b);
        mSpikesDown.move(a, b);
    }
    // if the user hits a door with a key and without a key
    if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCollisionDoor, true)) {
        if (keys > 0) {
            System.out.println("hit wall with key" + doorMap[0][34]);
            //doorMap[0][34] = 0;
            mCollisionDoor.setVisible(false);
            keys--;
            mLayerManager.append(mCollisionDoor);
            //mLayerManager.remove(mCollisionDoor);
            setPoints(getPoints() + 10);
            System.out.println("hit wall with key after changes" + doorMap[0][34]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("hit wall without key");
            mBackground.move(a, b);
            mCollisionBackground.move(a, b);
            mCollisionDoor.move(a, b);
            mAtmosphere.move(a, b);
            mCoin.move(a, b);
            mCoin2.move(a, b);
            mStairs.move(a, b);
            mMonster.move(a, b);
            mKey.move(a, b);
            mSpikesUp.move(a, b);
            mSpikesDown.move(a, b);
        }
    }
}

public void resetItems(int bg_x, int bg_y, int s_x, int s_y, int k_x, int k_y, int su_x, int su_y, int sd_x, int sd_y, int m_x, int m_y, int c_x, int c_y, int c2_x, int c2_y) {
    mBackground.setPosition(bg_x, bg_y);
    mCollisionBackground.setPosition(bg_x, bg_y);
    mCollisionDoor.setPosition(bg_x, bg_y);
    mStairs.setPosition(s_x, s_y);
    mKey.setPosition(k_x, k_y);
    mSpikesUp.setPosition(su_x, su_y);
    mSpikesDown.setPosition(sd_x, sd_y);
    mMonster.setPosition(m_x, m_y);
    mCoin.setPosition(c_x, c_y);
    mCoin2.setPosition(c2_x, c2_y);
}

public void stop() {
    mTrucking = false;

}



public void setVisible(int layerIndex, boolean show) {
    Layer layer = mLayerManager.getLayerAt(layerIndex);
    layer.setVisible(show);
}

public boolean isVisible(int layerIndex) {
    Layer layer = mLayerManager.getLayerAt(layerIndex);
    return layer.isVisible();
}

private void setDirection(int newDirection) {
    if (newDirection == mDirection) {
        return;
    }
    if (mDirection == kLeft) {
        mQuatsch.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR);
    } else if (mDirection == kRight) {
        mQuatsch.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_NONE);
    }
    mDirection = newDirection;
}

  public static int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

/**
 * @param aPoints the points to set
 */
public static void setPoints(int aPoints) {
    points = aPoints;
}

private void setState(int newState) {
    if (newState == mState) {
        return;
    }
    switch (newState) {
        case kStanding:
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kStandingSequence);
            mQuatsch.setFrame(0);
            break;
        case kRunning:
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequence);
            break;
        case kRunningUp:
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequenceUp);
            break;
        case kRunningDown:
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequenceDown);
            break;
        case kCoinSpin:
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kCoinSpinning);
            break;
        case kMonsterMoveUp:
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterUp);
            break;
        case kMonsterMoveDown:
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterDown);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    mState = newState;
}

private void setDragonState(int newState) {
    if (newState == dState) {
        return;
    }
    switch (newState) {
        case kStanding:
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kStandingSequence);
            mMonster.setFrame(0);
            break;
        case kMonsterMoveUp:
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterUp);
            break;
        case kMonsterMoveDown:
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterDown);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dState = newState;
}
}
```

I have taken out the matrixes for the levels just to save space for this question.

Comment: You might do better asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StephenC No, this is *not* suitable for Code Review, as per their FAQ, that is for *working* code only.  This code is *not* working.

Comment: I have solved this using a fairly cheap method, I just changed the emulator that i was using and it seems to be working fine now